# Delete * (All Files) from multiple blob folder

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have one requirement, where I am moving files from on-premises to Blob storage using ADF

In Blob I have one container,

Container name = Data

I have created many folders under container Data

/Data/Rwa_data/abc/abc.csv

/Data/Rwa_data/def/def.csv

/Data/Rwa_data/sss/sss.csv

Now I want to delete .csv files from all above 3 folders using data factory. I don't see any activity in ADF V2 for this.

Can someone let me know how I can delete files from multiple folders?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to delete all csv files from all subdirectories within Rwa_data? Also, does a PowerShell script also work for you?

Comment: Yes, I want to delete all csv files from all subdirectories within Raw_data. I am new to C# , if you can share some sample code for c# which I can call from ADF v2

Comment: If you want to use File/Folder structure then blobs might not best choice. See this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-decide-blobs-files-disks Looks like Azure Files is a good option for you. Otherwise if this is not for production you can try (preview) ADLS Gen 2 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/data-lake-storage/introduction

Answer (score 0):

The concept of (sub)folders in unknown to azure blob storage. You have a container with blobs (3 in your case) and that is it. So do not look for recursively delete functions.

Anyway, there isn't yet an activity to delete from azure blob storage, as you can read [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c3e0f121-2dd1-476b-8f3f-95853c3bbcfd/delete-blob-activity-needed-in-azure-data-factory-ui?forum=AzureDataFactory):

> This is absolutely an activity that we will make simpler in ADF.
>   In the meantime, here is a technique to delete Azure Storage Blobs and Azure Table rows w/o custom activities or Azure Batch, using the REST API:

The post [links to a blog](https://kromerbigdata.com/2018/03/15/azure-data-factory-delete-from-azure-blob-storage-and-table-storage/) that describes an alternative using ADF v2